# Add object to model list from a form ASP.NET Core Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I hope some can help me with this.

I have a list within a model and I want to add objects to that list using a form in a razor view before I save it to a database

This is the model that I have:

```
    public class ActivityForm
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public int Points { get; set; }

        public List<Award> Awards { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the code for my view:

```
@model ActivityForm

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Activity Details";
}

<section class="my-sm-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section-header d-flex mb-5">
            <h1 class="h-02 flex-grow-1">Activity Details</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="section-header d-flex mb-5">
                    <h1 class="h-04 flex-grow-1">Form</h1>
                </div>
                <form id="form" class="row g-3 w-90" asp-action="Create">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label asp-for="Name" class="form-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4"
                            placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)">
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <label asp-for="Description" class="form-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model =>
                            model.Description)</label>
                        <textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5"
                            placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)"></textarea>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label asp-for="StartDate" class="form-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model =>
                            model.StartDate)</label>
                        <input asp-for="StartDate" type="date" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)">
                        <span asp-validation-for="StartDate" class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label asp-for="EndDate" class="form-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndDate)</label>
                        <input asp-for="EndDate" type="date" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndDate)">
                        <span asp-validation-for="EndDate" class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-6">
                        <label asp-for="Points" class="form-label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Points)</label>
                        <input asp-for="Points" type="number" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Points)">
                        <span asp-validation-for="Points" class="invalid-feedback"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8 d-grid gap-2">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary mb-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#add-award">Add award</a>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                    data-bs-target="#cancel-activity">Cancel</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                    data-bs-target="#post-activity">Post Activity</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="section-header d-flex mb-5">
                    <h1 class="h-04 flex-grow-1">Awards</h1>
                </div>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Award name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Description</th>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>Award Name</td>
                                <td>Award Description</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Remove</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="modal" id="add-award" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content br-20 pd-20">
            <div class="modal-header justify-content-center">
                <h5 class="modal-title h-04 text-prim-color">Award details</h5>
            </div>
            <form class="row g-3">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row g-3">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label asp-for="Award.Name" class="form-label">Name</label>
                            <input asp-for="Award.Name" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <label asp-for="Award.Description" for="inputAddress" class="form-label">Description</label>
                            <textarea asp-for="Award.Description" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <input class="btn btn-primary w-100" type="submit" value="Confirm"></input>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My form is within a modal and when I click the submit button I want to create an Award object with the values from the form. After the object is created I want to add it to the Awards List and have the changes reflect on the view.

This is what the View looks like:
[View with modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLzda.png)

And this is how it will look like after the object has been added:
[View after object is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAY4i.png)

Comment: At which part are you facing an issue?

Comment: The part when I have to add an object to the Awards list.

Comment: So your main form calls the `Create` action but your modal form doesn't call any action. How about you try to create a new action e.g. `AddAward` that accepts an `Award` parameter, adds it to the `ActivityForm.Awards` list and returns your view?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos: I have thought about that but when I call `AddAward` and redirect back to the main view with the edited `ActivityForm` all its values are returned as null

Comment: `public int countAwards{ get{return Awards.Count;}}` and you can loop `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Awards[i].properties)`

Answer (score 0):

You should first fix some issues:

Right now your form does not have a binding for the `ActivityForm.Awards` property. You should change:

```
<tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>Award Name</td>
            <td>Award Description</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Remove</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

To:

```
<tbody>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Awards.Count; i++)
    {
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Awards[i].Name" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Awards[i].Description" />
        <tr>            
            <td>@Model.Awards[i].Name</td>
            <td>@Model.Awards[i].Description</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Edit</a>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Remove</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Documentation for binding model to a collection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#collections-1

Your form should wrap around both **Form** and **Awards** sections:

```
<form id="form" class="row g-3 w-90" asp-action="Create">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="section-header d-flex mb-5">
            <h1 class="h-04 flex-grow-1">Form</h1>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="section-header d-flex mb-5">
            <h1 class="h-04 flex-grow-1">Awards</h1>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</form>
```

You should also change:

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#post-activity">Post Activity</a>
```

to an actual submit button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100">Post Activity</button>
```

Now if you manually add some awards to the `Awards` list from your `Controller`,

```
return View(new ActivityForm
{
    Awards = new List<Award>
    {
        new Award { Name = "Name", Description = "Descr" },
        new Award { Name = "Award 2", Description = "Descr 2" }
    }
});
```

the awards will be displayed properly and also when you submit the form the `ActivityForm.Awards` list will be populated with the awards you added manually.

These issues need to be fixed before you go on and implement the add award form inside the modal.

Comment: From your new question it looks like your problem is half solved because you only followed half of what I said. Copied my answer to your new question.

Comment: I noticed that I completely overlooked the part where I had to wrap everything in the same form. After that everything worked as expected.